# Private variables in swift

Tags: ios, swift

When creating a class, what is the difference between these 2 implementations of creating a custom class in regards to security. They both work the exact same as far as I've used them, but have heard using private variables is the proper way to create classes

```
class Person {

    var name:String
    var age:Int

    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

and

```
class Person {

    private var _name: String
    private var _age: Int

    var name: String {
        set {
            self._name = newValue
        } get {
            return _name
        }
    }

    var age: Int {
        set {
            self._age = newValue
        } get {
            return _age
        }
    }

    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
    }
}
```

Comment: As written the second version is pointless.

Comment: This is style from other languages that don’t use Swift’s mechanisms.

Comment: either private or internal ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`private` is definitely recommended to use but only in cases when you want that kind of privacy for your properties.

Your second code is not ensuring any kind of privacy. That's just adding more code unnecessarily.

There can be a scenario where you want to keep the *write access* private to the type (`class/struct`) and allow *read access* outside the type. For that you can use `private(set)` access modifier with your properties, i.e.

```
class Person {
    private(set) var name: String
    private(set) var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps me to understand the between private variable and private(set) variables.

Comment: This code makes no sense. Practically you are declaring constants. If there is no other code in the class which modifies the properties declare them as `let`.

Comment: @vadian I'm aware of that. But I can't use `let` with `private(set)`.

Comment: `private(set)` is misused in this case. Once again practically the *variables* are constants. Unlike most other languages Swift provides real constants with `let`. `private(set)` is one useful if there is code which modifies the value inside the class.

Comment: @vadian I explained how `private(set)` can be used in this scenario. And not using `let` with it is what I've already raised a question for.

Comment: *Can* be used but ***should not*** be used.

Comment: @vadian Can't use. Here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60446284/privateset-with-let-properties-privateset-modifier-cannot-be-applied-to

Comment: It's the same issue. Take advantage of Swift's modern semantics. `private(set)` variables which are set only in the init method are **constants**, so declare them as constants, period.